# best appraoch to modify a site collection url inside sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection, administration, configuration

I have a site collection (of type enterprise KB) under the following URL `http//servername/customer/questions` where the customer is a wildcard managed path. now I want to change the site collection URL to be `http://servername/customer/generalquestions`.

so I am not sure how to change the site collection URL. I read that I can backup the current site collection, remove it,create a new site collection under the desired URL (customer/GeneralQuestion), restore the backup file on the new url.. but I am not sure if there is a more straightforward approach  to follow? using power shell or UI to accomplish this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no way to do this using the GUI, You have to rely on the PowerShell. there are 2 options in Powershell.

- use the [Copy-Spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161280.aspx)

  - `Copy-SPSite http://contoso/sites/OldTeam -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content -TargetUrl http://contoso/sites/NewTeam`
  - Now Run the Remove-Spsite to remove the old site.
- Another option is Using the BackUp and Restore

  - use Backup-spsite to get the backup
  - Now run the restore-spsite to restore on New URL
  - Now Run Remove-Spsite to remove the old site.

At the end you have to run the Search crawl so that old content removed and new added.

Comment: i think i will go with the backup/restore since i use it to do a back up for the my site collections, while i did not use the Copy-SPsite before.. so which approach is better ? second question, i know that SP allow to restore a site collection under the same content DB , although i should not do this since i will end up having duplicate GUIDs inside the old CS and inside the new SC .. so my question if i need to remove the old CS before restoring it on the new URL ,, because you mentioned i can restore on new url then remove the old CS ..

Comment: can you advice on my above 2 questions please?

Comment: Backup site collection is old traditional way to do. Yes you can delete the site collection before restore...Copy spsite is new commandi n SP2013, which will save u some time.

Comment: so do you have any idea if the end result of using backup/restore and using copy-spsite will  be the same ?

Comment: yes both are same, I tested both personally couple of times

Comment: I had 100% sucess in the backup and restore process

Comment: yes i will follow backup/restore also,, i tried using $site.Rename on my test machine but the old and new site collection did not work , i got unexpected error when try accessing the new url.and the old url is no more found ...

Comment: $Site.rename...Basically for changing from Path-based site collection ot HSNC. MSFT never advertise from path based to Path-based url rename.

Comment: so i will run these 3 commands:- 1) Backup-spsite -identity http//servername/customer/questions -path c:\c.bak –force
2) Remove-SPsite -identity http//servername/customer/questions
3) Restore-spsite -identity http://servername/customer/generalquestions -path c:\c.bak –force ,,,,,, i tired this on test machine and seems it is working well.. so can you advice

Comment: yes, go ahead. sfaeway

Answer (score 7):

Source: http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://servername/customer/questions
$site.Rename("http://servername/customer/generalquestions")
```

And you have more detailed info in http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573

Comment: so what is the differences between using $site.Rename and using backup/restore ?

Comment: I think is easier. I did not test it. Anyway, I recommend you do a test in a QA environment.

Comment: What's the point in doing a backup and restoring it if you are just changing the URL? I can't see any disadvantages with this approch as it does exactly what you need.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis now i tried using $site.Rename on my test machine but i get "An unexpected error has occurred."  when i tried accessing the new url,, while when i used backup/restore i was able to chnage the url successfully.

Comment: Did you see the unexpected error here http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573 ?

Comment: @jpussacq so why i need to go through all these problems,,, i can just use backup/resotre seems it is more error robust and faster.. what do you think ?

Comment: It is difficult to recommend. If you feel safe with backup and restore, go ahead. I would prefer to try the method rename. But I understand you.