# Team site name change

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-settings

I need to change team site name after it created and used. Is that possible? Can I save the same link or change it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you talking about the Title of the Site or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the title and same time it's interesting to me to know can I change the url also?

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Site Configuration" and then "Title, Description, and Logo"

You can use this URL

https://yoursharepointserver/yoursite/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx

[image]

More info in this link [Change the logo, title, and description of your team site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-theme-of-your-SharePoint-team-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818).

Note: you can change the URL if it is a subsite.

To change URL of site collection, see that: [best appraoch to modify a site collection url inside sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177103/best-appraoch-to-modify-a-site-collection-url-inside-sharepoint-2013)

But I think you cannot do it simple in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the title of the site collections by going to `site settings > Under Look and Feel` click on `Title, description, and logo.` here you can update the Title of your Site collection.

You cant change the URL of site collections once it created. there are couple of possibilities.

1. If site is not big enough then [save that as template include content](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/copy-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online/82de12e4-10b0-441a-9262-107031b09cc3) and create a new site collection on new url using that template.
2. create a new a site collection and move the content manually.
3. or create a new site collection and move the content using 3rd party
   tool. sharegate they offer free trail as well.

Comment: How to change URL of site collection? Could you please write it also.