# Changing Site Collection URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, url

I have a site collection `http://SPL-GT/sites/CP` and would like to change it to a shorter version of `http://SPL-Sharepoint`. How this can be done?

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177103/best-appraoch-to-modify-a-site-collection-url-inside-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Powershell.

This Blog might help you.
https://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/

it should not have managed path otherwise you need to follow the backup and restore approach.